# Bundled Python 3.5.1 app crashes when reading text files on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I have built an app using Python 3.5.1 and PyQt 5.6 under Mac OS X 10.11.4. Everything runs fine unbundled.

I have bundled it using Pyinstaller 3.2. Everything seems to work fine until the app reads text files from disk. File access is not the problem, since I can read all file properties using `libmagic`, which I do in order to filter out unwanted input formats, as these are user-selected files to be processed by my app.

The bundled app crashes exactly when the content of a text file is read into a variable in the usual way: `text = fobj.read()`. The prior file opening statement is successful, though.

To make things even more weird, this doesn't happen when the app is started from the terminal with the `open` command, only when it's started by double-clicking the app file. I have been reading about how Mac OS X treats app execution in these two ways, but apparently there should be no difference, as stated in the man page for the open command:

> The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you
>   had double-clicked the file's icon.

I have been struggling with this issue for days and cannot find a solution. I need to distribute my application, but asking users to start it from the terminal is not very appealing... Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly does it crash?

Comment: The app just dies. No error messages. The Mac OS X console doesn't give me any useful info either. I have also built the app in Windows 7 (Virtualbox VM). Same exact result! Also, neither the Mac or Windows binaries will run at all on computers other than mine.